# "Downgrade" ClickOnce application

Tags: clickonce, downgrade

What is the recommended way of offering the users of my ClickOnce application a way to downgrade to the previous version? (In case the new version doesn't work on their machine)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the ClickOnce deployment setup, leave the minimum required version as the older version.  This will give them the choice of whether or not to upgrade.  If they upgrade, then decide they want to revert back to the older version, then they can do so through add/remove programs.

If you set the minimum required version as the new version, they will not have the choice to go back to the older version.

Comment: Is it possible to do this with more than 2 versions? To let users choose what version they want?

Comment: I do not believe so.  At least not through such a clean and simple mechanism.  You may be able to do some sort of custom setup / organization in your ClickOnce location to allow users to browse and install various different versions, but without experimenting a bit I cannot tell you what the specifics of such a setup would be.

Comment: @Espo - No.  It's built in to ClickOnce to keep the current version and one prior.  Anything beyond that will have to be some custom solution that you implement.